# How do i execute a program based on a keypress from a specific USB keyboard?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, remapping

I've been given one of these ubiquitous usb-sleep buttons which is basically a supersimple usb-keyboard. It's a big button that sends a SLEEP keypress to the computer when you slam it. But that is pretty boring. I'd love to remap it to do something more fun but I can't figure out how to bind to only the sleep press from the button and not from my ordinary keyboard.

The button identifies as

```
Bus 001 Device 035: ID 1130:600d Tenx Technology, Inc.
```

I'd like to know if there's either

1. a way of mapping a key from a specific keyboard to an action OR
2. a way of remapping the sleep key from a specific keyboard to a new key-code or something like that.

Comment: You could use your WM to program keypresses like this. And I hate to plug my own work (it is in disrepair right now), but [kbmon](https://github.com/adamnew123456/kbmon) may help you out.

Comment: Problem is my WM doesn't seem to allow for separate configurations for different simultaneous keyboards. I'd like to bind my "magic button" without messing up the sleep button on my main keyboard.

Comment: In that case, you will certainly need a separate keyboard binder that recognizes multiple keyboards. You can probably find them around, but the one I know best is [my own.](https://github.com/adamnew123456/SmallWM). (Not that I'd recommend it if you can find another, but mine works for what you suggest).

Comment: Corrections - the link is [kbmon](https://github.com/adamnew123456/kbmon)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the key code in xev? Run xev in terminal and see if pressing it gives you the keycode. If so, you may be able to set a xmodmap rule for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *showkey* command as root if *xev* doesn't work for you. Sometimes you need to use *showkey* command if *xev* command doesn't produce any usable output. Just start *showkey* command as root.

Comment: Can you add more detail? This is a very low quality answer

Comment: The question was asked 2 years ago. I don't even have the button left and the question was not about how to identify the key but how to remap the button without affecting my main keyboard.